# connecting to a remote java application

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ports

I have to build a server/client chat room in java as a school project, and I want to know if I can connect to that server from the world network (not local network) using the IP address and ports (I wanted to host it but I realized too late that I should have built a web app not a desktop one). My app is using Transmission Content Protocol(TCP) sockets. I have tried to connect to the app by using the public IP and the port that I have opened in firewall. I can post the code if needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: "... and i want to know if i can connect to that server from the world network(not local network)..."  Maybe, but very probably *not*, because of firewall settings on your school's network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your networks firewall settings let you do it, of course you can connect.

Now, your computer has an internal ip address, which is like *192.168.xxx.xxx* and your router has an external ip address which is unique.

Set up your router to forward connections. Steps to do it may change for each router but the point is to forward **all** connections coming to this router with a port number you have declared, to a internal ip address and a port number.

In your client side, your connection statement will have your external ip adress and the port number you have written in your router settings. In your server side, it will listen your internal ip address and the port number your router forwards to.

To be clear;

Client  ---"xx.xx.xx.xx:9999"--->  Router  ---"192.168.xx.xx:8888"---> Server

As you see above, the router forwards all the connections coming to 9999. port, to 192.168.xx.xx address and 8888. port.

Comment: aham, that makes sense. So not only i need to allow it past firewall i also need to mess around with router settings. Ill get to it and report back. thanks for help